# Asynchronous loading of images

Tags: iphone

I have loaded some images please tell me how to use asynchrounous loading of images

Comment: Would you explain it spending some more words?

Comment: i get json images i want load the images but very time consume so i don't know how to use the asynchrounous methods to load images

Answer (score 2):

Make use of EGOImageView assuming you want to display the downloaded image in an *UIImageView*, it's really easy (just initialize it with a placeholder image and set the URL of the image to download).

http://developers.enormego.com/view/what_if_images_on_the_iphone_were_as_easy_as_html

If you don't want to display the image, but just want asynchronous downloading, make use of EGOImageLoader.

Just make sure your class conforms to the *EGOImageLoaderObserver* protocol and implement 2 delegate methods and you're done ...

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
       imageLoader = [EGOImageLoader sharedImageLoader]; // ivar, so we can remove the observer in the dealloc ...
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
   [imageLoader removeObserver:self];
   [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSString *urlString = @"http://www.wimwauters.be/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/steve-jobs.jpg";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
   [imageLoader loadImageForURL:url observer:self];            
}

#pragma mark - EGOImageLoaderObserver

- (void)imageLoaderDidLoad:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
   NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
   UIImage *theImage = [userInfo objectForKey:@"image"];

   // do something with the image, e.g. display it in an ImageView ...
}

- (void)imageLoaderDidFailToLoad:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
   NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
   NSError *error = [userInfo objectForKey:@"error"];
   if (error) 
   {
    // handle the error
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about downloading images in the background?

This tutorial by Jeff LaMarche is a good solution - http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/downloading-images-for-table-without.html